# How to pass a digraph to a different process and node?

Tags: erlang

I have created a [**digraph**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html#add_vertex-2) term on process A and I want to pass this digraph to a process on another node. Whenever I use this digraph on the other process I am getting errors such as:

```
** {badarg,
   [{ets,insert,[598105,{"EPqzYxiM9UV0pplPTRg8vX28h",[]}],[]},
    {digraph,do_add_vertex,2,[{file,"digraph.erl"},{line,377}]},
```

Becasuse a **digraph** is based on ETS, it appears that this is quite more complicated, making a digraph pretty much standalone on the process it was created. I have found this entry that reveals a similar problem : [ETS on a different process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448803/unable-to-use-erlang-ets-in-receive-block)

I know I can create the digraph in a **server** an then connect to it through otp messages, but I cannot do that in my architecture. All nodes can communicate using a specific approach designed to pass the state along as Terms.

It appears to me that having digraphs sent accross different nodes that cannot directly communicate with each other is not possible. Overall, **it appears that a digraph cannot be directly serialized**. I am thinking that I can "unwind" the digraph as a list of vertices and edges and then transmit and recreate it on the other process (not efficient, performing or elegant). Any thoughts on a better way to **serialize** it ? Is there a way to serialize the digraph state out of the ETS store ?

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can serialize/deserialize a digraph like this;

```
serialize({digraph, V, E, N, B}) ->
    {ets:tab2list(V),
     ets:tab2list(E),
     ets:tab2list(N),
     B}.

deserialize({VL, EL, NL, B}) ->       
    DG = {digraph, V, E, N, B} = case B of 
       true -> digraph:new();
       false -> digraph:new([acyclic])
    end,
    ets:delete_all_objects(V)
    ets:delete_all_objects(L)
    ets:delete_all_objects(N)
    ets:insert(V, VL)
    ets:insert(E, EL)
    ets:insert(N, NL)
    DG.
```

And this is the code I used to test this;

```
passer() ->
    G = digraph:new(),
    V1 = digraph:add_vertex(G),
    V2 = digraph:add_vertex(G),
    V3 = digraph:add_vertex(G),
    digraph:add_edge(G, V1, V2, "edge1"),
    digraph:add_edge(G, V1, V3, "edge2"),
    Pid = spawn(fun receiver/0),
    Pid ! serialize(G).

receiver() ->
     receive
         SG = {_VL, _EL, _NL, _B} ->
            G = deserialize(SG),
            io:format("Edges: ~p~n", [digraph:edges(G)]),
            io:format("Edges: ~p~n", [digraph:vertices(G)])
     end.
```

Pretty ugly solution but works. I think this is the only way pass digraph between nodes since ets tables cannot be shared between nodes.

Edit: remove unnecessary loops

Comment: Thanks cashmere and Pascal, you both have the same approach and solution. One issue: The boolean that is used for the deseralization creation ( digraph:new(B) ) fails. It expects a few items "cyclic" for example.

Comment: Just another issue. If you transfer the data out of a process/node and then back to that same process/node, the original ETS data might still contain the original data. If you recreate the digraph on a process that already had it, then adding edges will fail with a badmatch. To resolve this I have added "ets:delete_all_objects(V)" and so on ( for E and N as well) right before those ets:inserts. That made it to cleanup the ETS recipient prior to inserting it back there.

Comment: though, you need to take care of memory while doing this. If the ets tables are small, it would be okay, but if they are large, it might run the vm down. i think...

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution, but it relies on the structure of the variable returned by digrapgh:new(), so I am not sure that it will be compatible with future version.

```
D = digraph:new(),
...
%some code modifying D
...
{digraph,Vertices,Edges,Neighbours,Cyclic} = D, % get the table Id of the 3 tables containing D values
% It should be preferable to use the record definition of the digraph module
%-record(digraph, {vtab = notable :: ets:tab(),
%         etab = notable :: ets:tab(),
%         ntab = notable :: ets:tab(),
%             cyclic = true  :: boolean()}).
LV = ets:tab2list(Vertices),
LE = ets:tab2list(Edges),
LN = ets:tab2list(Neighbours),
...
% then serialize and send all this variables to the target node, ideally in one single tuple like 
% {my_digraph_data,LV,LE,LN,Cyclic} or using refs to avoid the mix of messages, 
% and on reception on the remote node:

receive
    {my_digraph_data,LV,LE,LN,Cyclic} ->
        Dcopy = digrapgh:new(Cyclic),
        {digraph,Vertices,Edges,Neighbours,_Cyclic} = Dcopy,
        ets:insert(Vertices,LV),
        ets:insert(Edges,LE),
        ets:insert(Neighbours,LN),
        Dcopy;
...
```

and that's it.

> **Note**: If you are testing this in the same shell, then make sure to change the name of `Vertices`, `Edges`, and `Neighbours` in the
>   spawned process' `receive` expression otherwise it will fail with
>   `badmatch` (as they have already been bound when matching `D`).