# Saving a digraph to mnesia is hindered because of its side-effects

Tags: erlang

**Updated**

The digraph library in erlang implements a data type that is side-effectful. Each operation on the data type saves its new state in an ets table -- instead of returning an altered version of itself, which is more common in functional languages.

The problem from a usage perspective, is that it impedes my effort to store or pass around the state in a convenient way by requiring me to first "collect" the state before I can start to juggle it around.

The closest solution I have seen so far is a [serializer/deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552796/how-to-pass-a-digraph-to-a-different-process-and-node), but these have the drawback that they are tied to the current structure of digraphs instead of operating on an abstract type -- which prevents a future proof solution.

**Update**

Pascal pointed out another serializer which utilizes the interface of digraph, and hence eliminates the drawback mentioned above. It is obviously much better, albeit still inconvenient, but I see no better alternative.

---

What is your recommendation on how to store digraphs? Should I go with a different data type altogether?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your concern. The fact that a digraph is stored in ETS is transparent in the user interface, so you might want to chnge this either to exchange a digraph with another process, make a copy, or have a permanent storage in case of crash.

For the 2 first topics, it is quite easy to retrieve the definition of a digraph in a tuple `{Cyclic,Protect,[Vertice],[edge]}` and then exchange it:

```
digraph_To_Tuple(Di) ->
    Opt = digraph:info(Di),
    Vs = [digraph:vertex(Di,X) || X <- digraph:vertices(Di)],
    Es = [digraph:edge(Di,X) || X <- digraph:edges(Di)],
    {proplists:get_value(cyclicity,Opt),proplists:get_value(protection,Opt),Vs,Es}.

clone (Di) -> 
    {Cyclic,Protect,Vs,Es} = digraph_To_Tuple(Di),                                                                        
    Do = digraph:new([Cyclic,Protect]),                                                                            
    [digraph:add_vertex(Do,V,N) || {V,N} <- Vs ],  
    [digraph:add_edge(Do,E,S,D,N) || {E,S,D,N} <- Es], 
    Do.
```

The last topic is a real problem since an ets is destroyed as soon as the process which created it dies. There are some means to giveaway the ownership to other process, but in this case the independence with the ets implementation is lost. A better possibility is to create the digraph in a process and pass it to other process in charge to manipulate them.

But I do not see any mean to have another type of storage without re-writing a part or the whole module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the question a little to better convey my concern.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Erlang's [sofs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sofs.html) (set of sets) module to get a complete immutable data structure that contains all the data required to rebuild an identical graph afterwards

```erlang
clone(Digraph) ->
  Family = sofs:digraph_to_family(Digraph),
  sofs:family_to_digraph(Family).
```