# How does one serialize a digraph in Erlang or Elixir for export purposes

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am using [Erlang's digraph module](https://erldocs.com/r14b/stdlib/digraph) for storing Directed Acyclic Graphs ([DAGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)). So for argument's sake here is a super simple graph (using Elixir):

```
gr = :digraph.new()
:digraph.add_vertex(gr, "A")
:digraph.add_vertex(gr, "B")
:digraph.add_vertex(gr, "C")
:digraph.add_edge(gr, "A", "B")
:digraph.add_edge(gr, "A", "C")
```

which looks like this:

[image]

We can see it's all worked:

```
iex(7)> :digraph.vertices(gr)
["A", "C", "B"]
iex(8)> :digraph.edges(gr)
[[:"$e" | 0], [:"$e" | 1]]
iex(9)> :digraph.out_neighbours(gr, "A")
["C", "B"]
iex(10)> :digraph.out_neighbours(gr, "B")
[]
iex(11)> :digraph.out_neighbours(gr, "C")
[]
iex(12)> :digraph_utils.is_acyclic(gr)
true
```

Now I'm going to be adding and removing more vertices and edges, but I would like to transmit these graphs to applications outside of the Elixir/Erlang ecosystem such as [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/). Is there a standardized way to serialize digraphs into some industry standard readable format (json or xml for example), such as [JGF](http://jsongraphformat.info/), Netlix's [Falcor JSON Graph](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/jsongraph.html) format, or other?

I could write my own serializer but I'd prefer something pre-existing. I can't find anything that does this in [digraph](http://erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html) or [digraph_utils](http://erlang.org/doc/man/digraph_utils.html).

Comment: For those who got here wanting to serialize/de-serialize `digraph`s to save process state, pass graphs between processes etc. within BEAM-based languages: [How to pass a digraph to a different process and node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552796/how-to-pass-a-digraph-to-a-different-process-and-node)

Answer (score 5):

Searching there are various solutions for exporting digraph data to various popular formats, but nothing canonical Two of the most popular of these formats are [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) and [GraphML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML).

Some Elixir and Erlang libraries for exporting digraphs to various formats:

- https://github.com/mikowitz/graphvix
- https://github.com/jabarszcz/digraph_viz
- https://github.com/fenollp/erlang-dot

Some Elixir and Erlang examples of updating the front-end in soft realtime using js libs such as [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) and web sockets:

- http://blog.songsaboutsnow.com/elixir/graphviz/2018/06/26/graphvix-part1.html
- https://github.com/swelham/digraph_viewer
- https://rshestakov.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/extended-example-with-graphviz-updates-via-websockets/

Comment: Unfortunately many of these are more than 5 years old and, while that may be fine, I'm just a bit worried about packages being maintained. Nevertheless https://github.com/fenollp/erlang-dot looks good especially when combined with some of the solutions outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595493/reading-dot-files-in-javascript-d3. If you want to add that last url to your answer, I will accept it. Many thanks for your hard work, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: actually erlang-dot doesn't seem to complile under Elixir, graphvix seems to be a _competitor_ to digraph and looks very patchy because it uses a genserver to store graphs (DDOS risk), while digraph_viz doesn't give me an export option that I can see. I'm afraid none of these really answers my question that I can see unless you can show me otherwise.

Comment: Graphvix is a wrapper for digraph and not a competitor as evident here: https://github.com/mikowitz/graphvix/blob/e437a1dcdbca5ce64a3d7504a1b09e4f90daafeb/lib/graphvix/graph.ex#L74
It also does not make use of a gen_server. However, making use of a gen_server does not entail any security risks. It is quite common for a "lib" to use gen servers to hold state. Meanwhile, digraph_vis indeed has functions for exporting as evident here: https://github.com/jabarszcz/digraph_viz/blob/a961d940eb3f0b516d46777c29e03a918027d5dd/src/digraph_viz.erl#L29

Comment: perfect thank you. Please show some code in the answer and I will accept it. Note that I need a serialization, that will not necessarily be written to disk but may need to be transmitted over the wire via zeromq or websockets etc.